# I have Messages in iCloud but messages still not perfectly synced

Tags: iphone, icloud, messages

I have Messages in iCloud on my iPhone (6S, latest OS version 11.4) - or at least I think I do: In iPhone Settings -> [my Apple profile] -> iCloud I have Messages switched to on. I also have Messages on my MacBook Pro, which has the latest version of Mac OS.

However today my iPhone was off because it didn't have enough charge. My Mom (who also has an iPhone with iMessage) sent me a message. The message showed up on my Mac. However even after I restored power to my iPhone and restarted it a couple times, the message never showed up on my iPhone.

So what is going wrong? I thought this, at least, would be solved by Messages in iCloud.

Comment: Can you verify you have Messages signed in with the same Apple ID on both devices?  Was this ever working (once you met all the requirements)?  Also, I don't believe the sync is instantaneous; it could take several hours.  How long have you waited for the sync to take place?

Comment: Yes, they are both signed in with the same ID. I am not sure if it was ever working, this is the first time I've noticed anything since I set it up. But I didn't know it could take several hours. It's only been like 10 minutes here. So I guess I will continue to wait.

Comment: What would be a lot better is if Apple provided a button somewhere to "Sync Now" so that we could see for ourselves. That option is in Preferences on the Mac version of Messages, but I don't think there's anything similar for the iPhone version.

Comment: [Here's a good overview](https://appletoolbox.com/2018/01/how-to-use-icloud-message-sync/#What_You_Should_Know_about_Messages_in_iCloud_Feature) of how this process works and the requirements.  I don't think it was ever meant to be a real-time sync because that's not how iCloud currently works.

Answer (score 1):

While there is no sync now button, you could force one by turning iCloud Sync off and then back on.